# Is it possible to create visited map with leaflet or d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I am looking for visited map created before with d3.js or leaflet.js. But I couldnt find anything.

For illustrate this we have a csv like this:

```
 person----visited_city----year

alfanso---------Boston----------2012
mike------------NY--------------2013
alfanso---------LOS------------2014
```

I want to show person with visited states on map.

How can we do visited map with this techniques?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain a "visited map" is, i'm unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: I edited the question.Maybe this time you are familiar with this

Comment: You just want to color the visited states?  Yes, this is possible with both d3.js or leaflet.  Here's a d3 [example](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312) which is coloring at the state level.

Comment: Infact I want to like this:http://d3.artzub.com/wbca/  But this is so complicated.And I dont know how can I code like this

Comment: I can do it =) Write me to skype... Maybe I help you =)